# MongoDB ReadPreference

Tags: c#, mongodb

I was wondering which ReadPreference takes precedence when querying a collection created using `.WithReadPreference(ReadPreference.Secondary)` whilst having the connection string such as `mongodb://host.example.com/?readPreference=primary` ?

Comment: Neither, you're creating a collection.

Comment: @john Neither ? could you elaborate more on how does that affect any subsequent queries ?

Comment: This explains how [write operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/distributed-write-operations/) work. The documentation wording suggests that the default [connection string](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) read preference is "primary" and it therefore seems reasonable to conclude (as I would expect) that specifying a readpreference on an individual query would override this. _Creating a collection_ is of course a write operation, however.

Comment: No solid documentation on that, i'd have to spin up a replica-set to find out !. I am obviously not talking about creating a collection here, as i am talking about read preference.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question then? P.S. Considering a question the other day was "can you rebuild a solution too many times?", I don't typically default to assuming that people aren't trying something very stupid.

Comment: Regardless of documentation on it, it seems to be a logical conclusion. What would be the point of building .WIthReadPreference(...) into the driver if it never did anything - which it couldn't if it can't override the connection string value since the documentation states that the connection string value has "primary" by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does.
I setup a replica-set and verified that using `.WithReadPreference(ReadPreference.Secondary)` when creating a collection overrides the preference provided at the connection string level.

Comment: How did you confirm that it overrides it?